Synthetic proof for a Van Aubel Generalization
There is an interesting generalization of Van Aubel's Theorem, discovered by Dao Thanh Oai.
https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Geometry/DaosVanAubel.shtml
Two short proofs by Grégoire Nicollier, using complex numbers, are given there. I tried to find a synthetic proof for the general case but I failed.
For a dynamic version of it see:
http://dynamicmathematicslearning.com/dao-van-aubel-generalization.html
I found proofs only for special cases (eg. if the quadrilateral ABCD is a rectangle; or if one of the angles $\alpha$ or $\beta$ equals 0). I wonder if there is also a purely geometric (synthetic) proof for the general case of this phenomenon? It would be great if anybody could could provide such a proof.
